# How to have MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter set the content-length

Tags: java, spring

I'm returning JSON data from my Spring controller by with @ResponseBody. Similar to this:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/someMethod.json")
public @ResponseBody MyClass someMethod(@RequestParam Long someVal, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new MyClass(someVal);
}
```

The MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter always returns null for getContentLength(), which results in content-length header of -1.

I need the content-length to be set accurately (to solve a separate issue on the client-side, which I'm unable to access to fix).

What is the simplest way to have this class calculate the content length of the generated JSON, and set this in the content-length header?

I don't want to write my own JSON generator and return json strings, because I have a lot of API methods that will need this "fix".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see the answer that I set for this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840190/set-content-length-using-mappingjacksonhttpmessageconverter/

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, you should never have to set the content-length of a HTTP header manually.  Would be quite dangerous to be able to tell a service that there is more or less data than what is actually being sent.  It seems the underlying technology (spring in your case) should isn't actually handling the json conversion properly.

Maybe the MyClass object is not being converted to json properly, and thats why there is no content?

Comment: The content is generated perfectly fine normally. Very occasionally (<1%) the client code is saying the message has no content. By inspecting with Fiddler, I know the server is definately sending the content correctly. No difference with any other message being sent before or after it. When I tested with hardcoded content and content-length, the client no longer had a problem.

Comment: Hmm, not sure, perhaps something else about the request from the client is confusing the server?  Maybe something funny in the request header from the client is tricking the serer to think it cannot serialize the response in JSON?

Comment: as mentioned before, the server is working perfectly fine. But it sets the content-length to -1 instead of the true value. Setting to -1 is valid http, and normal practice in many scenarios. In 99% of cases the client consumes this fine. But there is some kind of asynchornous processing bug on the client, a race condition, that causes the occasional problem. If the packet includes a value other than -1, then the client-side bug does not occur, and it always preccesses fine.